# What is the valid regex for followign case

Tags: javascript, regex, active-directory

I need to valid string with following criteria

- Must be less than 20
- should not contain any of this characters
  " [ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ ,
- trailing . is not allowed but can be in between
- no trailing space is allowed

Actually, I want to validate samAccountName of Active directory.

I found [this](http://blog.vertigion.com/post/18028230414/active-directory-validate-group-samaccountname) but it invalid when using with javascript.

Comment: You did found a good link but did you gave any attempt to solve this problem ?

Comment: I tried to fix the error with https://regex101.com/ but it turn out the validation didnot work. I changed the 63 to 20. BUt it was passing any length. And I really don't understand regex :-) very complex for me

Comment: @veshu Is my regex (see answer below) working for you? Which language do you code?

Comment: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is a good place to start with regex.

Comment: @netblognet i was testing and i need it to test using javascript

Comment: @noob I understand your point but i can't study such big topic just for thing which i randomly require because I got the best regex in SO without trouble most of time. Also consider the severity of my regex it needs to be more accurate than what I will write after reading few hours. I believe SO is here for such condition, I can't learn whatever i need. If you are good at Regex then help

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var re = /^[^"\[\]:;\|=\+\*\?<>\/\\. ][^"\[\]:;\|=\+\*\?<>\/\\\n\r\t]{0,17}[^"\[\]:;\|=\+\*\?<>\/\\ \n\r\t]$/;
var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
var results = [];
var i = 0;
for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)){
  results[i] = matches;
  for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
    alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
  }
  i++;
}
```

At first it matches exactly one char which isn't in the forbidden group and which isn't " " or ".". Then it matches 0-17 chars which aren't in your forbidden group. At last it matches exactly one char which isn't in the forbidden group and which isn't " " or ".".

So it matches a string from 1-19 chars, which fits the allowed char-group and hasn't a traling space or dot.

Comment: I was testing your regex. kind wired it passess following what i have tested http://jsfiddle.net/9mutp08b/1/

Comment: Two questions. Can't see why "test" is in your invalid-array? Second question. Could it be, that you meant leading and trailing spaces instead of trailing?

Comment: Re-edited my sample. Please try again. Now it should fit.

Comment: test is random text it can be any text, yes I meant both end.

Comment: No, I meant "test" without leading and trailing spaces. It's in your invalid array, but I think it's a valid input. Nevertheless, retry the regex above. It should work now.

Comment: oh, it must be "test.". "tst." is invalid but 'tes.t' is valid. Also this link looks working can you check http://blog.vertigion.com/post/18028230414/active-directory-validate-group-samaccountname and make it work with javascript..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106843/discussion-between-veshu-and-netblognet).